# Pagination stops at page 6

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

The loop below works fine, apart from the fact that the pagination will always stop on page 6. No matter what arguments i specify, it will never show more than 6 pages.

Does anyone know why?

```
<?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;            
    $idxargs = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '1',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );

    $idxloop = new WP_Query( $idxargs );                   
?>

    <?php if ($idxloop->have_posts()) : while ( $idxloop->have_posts() ) : $idxloop->the_post(); ?>                  
        <?php the_title(); ?>                    
    <?php endwhile; ?>

   <?php next_posts_link( __( 'Next') ); ?>
   <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Prev' ) ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to use pagination from a different query is always fraught with potential disaster. `next_posts_link` accepts a second argument, `$max_pages`, which may solve your issue if you pass it properly:

```
next_posts_link( __( 'Next'), $idxloop->max_num_pages );
```

However, the *real* answer to this question is to adjust your query *before* the template. Adjusting the default query via a new `WP_Query` or by using `query_posts` is quite simply *doing it wrong*, despite the millions of examples on the web you will see that do exactly that.

The preferred method for this is using a [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action along with a [conditional check](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to apply it to the specific type of query you want to adjust:

```
function wpa64918_homepage_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa64918_homepage_posts_per_page', 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how does that function know what the "is_main_query" is on the page? I have about 3 loops on the homepage (aside from the main 1).

Comment: the main query is the query that happens before the template is loaded, based on the requested page. WP sets a variable in the query object to identify it as such. see the [action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) page to see the general process of how a request is parsed, posts are loaded, then the template is loaded. this is why it's inefficient to call query_posts or create a new query to replace the original, because you're just overwriting or not using a query that's already happened before you ever reached the template.

Comment: The function seems to trigger the extra pages in the pagination, but most of the higher numbers are 404 errors. I've cleared my permalinks too... thx for help

Comment: it's difficult to say without seeing your full template. you've got an issue with your loops polluting the global variables or being used incorrectly somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

How many posts per page have you specified inside your Settings -> Reading screen?

Also, try placing a `wp_reset_query();` at the top of your script, too.

**UPDATE:**

Try this loop:

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&paged='.$paged.''); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php next_posts_link( __( 'Next') ); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Prev' ) ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Changing posts per page in settings seems to trigger something. It was set at 5. Strangely the more i up this setting, the less pages show in pagination (20 only shows 2 pages). I set it to "2" and now i have 16 pages (thought some of these are empty). Seems this is on the right track, thx.

Comment: Also `wp_reset_query();` at top doesn't help. I even deleted all loops before the problem loop.